# Steps involved when showing this induced map on homology is welldefined

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification

I am showing that $H_0(X,R)=R$ when $X$ is a path-connected topological space. Let the zero boundary map be $\partial_0 : C_0(X) \to R$, $c \mapsto 0$.

Define a map $\varphi : C_0(X) \to R$ by $\sum_i c_i \sigma_i \mapsto \sum_i c_i$.

I would like to show that the induced map $\widetilde{\varphi}: H_0(X) \to R$ is welldefined.

> In particular, could someone please tell me if the following reasoning
>   is the correct reasoning:

(1) What needs to be verified (in order to show that $\widetilde{\varphi}$ is welldefined) is that if $[x]=[y]\in H_0$ then $\widetilde{\varphi}([x])=\widetilde{\varphi}([y])$.

(2) Note that $\varphi$ is linear and therefore $\widetilde{\varphi}([y])=\varphi(y) = \varphi(x+z) = \varphi(x) + \varphi(z)$ where $z \in \mathrm{im } \partial_1$.

(3) Hence it is enough to show that if $z \in \mathrm{im } \partial_1$ then $\varphi(z)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. More generally, if you are dealing with similar algebraic structures and their quotients (groups, vector spaces, rings, etc.) then a map $\phi:G/G' \to H/H'$ will be well-defined whenever $\phi(G') \subseteq H'.$ In this particular case $H' = 0.$

Comment: I think you are addressing my main concern in your question: the argument in my question is built on the fact that $\varphi$ us *linear*. In your answer, $\phi$ is a homomorphism (for groups, vector spaces, rings etc.) and therefore linear (in the sense that $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x)+\phi(y)$. If the map didn't have this property then the proof would be much more complicated, right?

Comment: Yes, by "map" I mean a morphism in the suitable category. That is, it should preserve the algebraic operations we're dealing with.

Comment: Succicnt +1 ${}$